# File Explorer keep opening by itself in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, files

I installed a fresh setup of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by erasing my full hard-disk. After installation when computer opens, file explorer is automatically opening its multiple windows. Because of that computer becomes slow.

After that I closed all its instances and opened firefox. After some time, again multiple windows of file explorer opened automatically. This can be seen here:

[image: multiple windows shown]

Is there any malware infection or any other software issue? Please help!

Comment: Does the same issue occur if you boot from your LiveUSB and use the "Try Ubuntu" environment?

Comment: I did not try that. Will try it too.

Comment: In "Try Ubuntu" mode, I am not able to open file explorer.
But a strange thing is happening: when I opened firefox browser, it is automatically keep opening 'home-page' which is start.ubuntu.com And I am not able to even type or try a URL, as it itself leading to start.ubuntu.com I can see on the left bottom of firefox: "waiting for start.ubuntu.com"

Comment: That is a very unusual series of problems. Are you *sure* your hardware and network are working properly?

Comment: Is the machine a notebook or desktop? If it's a desktop then disconnect the keyboard and see if that behaviour occurs or not. 
If it's a notebook, then only if you want/can, remove any external keyboard and also disconnect the builtin keyboard and see if this fixes the behaviour.

Comment: It is a notebook. I will try this.

Comment: Thanks. It was a keyboard issue. I disabled my built-in keyboard and used an external keyboard. It is not happening now.